# Node.js modularize functions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two functions, one "calcID" that calculates if a passed demo_id matches the document _id after doing some calculations with MongoDB aggregation framework and mongoose, and another function called "getDemoID" which uses that previous function to get all documents with that calculated ID and then do further processing of documents (e.g log some ID's) ...:

```
var calcID = function(demo_id) {
    //e.g. demo_id = 928106329281
    var result = FlexPotenzial.aggregate([ 
        {
            $addFields: {
                subID:  {
                    "$eq": [{"$trunc": {"$divide": ["$_id", 1000000]}},+demo_id]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": { subID : true }
        }   
    ])      
}

exports.getDemoID = function(req,res) {
    calcID(req.params.demo_id, function(err, flPot) {
    flPot => {
            for (let doc of flPot) {
                console.log(doc.id);
            }           
        }
    }
    ).catch(e => { console.log(e); res.error(e);});
}
```

The problem is, my calcID function is apparently not returning anything, altough I tested the aggregation in mongoose shell and the syntax is correct, but I don't get anything returned when passing the id as url parameter in the route url (get method)...
I would like to modularize my functions a bit more, so I can reuse code that's often repeated...

My question now is, how can I pass the found documents in the aggregation stage to my second function and use them there ? I am quite new to Node or in general javascript styles and I'm not sure what the type of the returned aggregation framework result is... maybe it is not possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either pass a callback to aggregate OR use `.exec()` when you are done to get a promise from it. A lot of things in mongoose are .then()-able even though they are not real promises, and Aggregate is one of those. If you do aggregate(...).exec() however you always get a real promise.

Since we are talking express here, it's middleware all the way. Just stick your stuff to `req` and move along.

```
async function myMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  const { demo_id } = req.params;
  req.results = await FlexPotenzial.aggregate([ 
      {
          $addFields: {
              subID:  {
                  "$eq": [{"$trunc": {"$divide": ["$_id", 1000000]}},+demo_id]
              }
          }
      },
      {
          "$match": { subID : true }
      }   
  ]).exec();
  next();
}

// All routes matching this will use the middleware
app.use('/aggregate-me/:demo_id*', myMiddleware);

// And then we can access req.results anywhere further down the stream....
app.get('/aggregate-me/:demo_id/something', doSomething); 
app.get('/aggregate-me/:demo_id/somethingElse', doSomethingElse);
```

You can also use middleware for single routes

```
app.get('/something-entirely-different/:demo_id', myMiddleware, (req,res)=>{
    res.json(results);
});
```

Or even:

```
app.get('/abc', [tonsof, middleware, inAnArray], endpoint);
```

The rule is to keep using `next()` to continue the middleware-chain and some sort of `res.end` to end it.

Comment: thanks, but my other question was, how can I use that function inside the other function? What happens with my result and how can I pass that result to the other function?

Comment: Ah sorry. Reading comprehension is nil. I'll revise!

Comment: just a follow-up question: Can I send my json results from myMiddleware to the browser with res.json(result) and then still use next() to pass my data to another middleware function? Or is this not possible anymore after res.send() or res.json() ? Or would I just have to set headers again somehow?

Comment: Once you send the response `send(),end(),sendFile(),json()` (and I'm sure there are more ways to send a response in express) the middleware chain ends. You cannot add more to it. You'll either have to look into response streaming or websockets I guess. But I would say the normal thing is to just do more requests - ajax-requests if you need more data or update old data without refreshing the page.